# Updating non-current record from a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access *form* that queries items from a table.  For example, if this is my table:

```
ID | Type | Active | Leading | DaysBehind
1     A      Yes       Yes      0
2     A      Yes       No       20
3     A      Yes       No       40
4     B      Yes       Yes      0
5     B      Yes       No       30
6     C      Yes       Yes      0
```

then a search (*on my form*) for Type=A returns:

```
txtID | cmbType | cmbActive | cmbLeading | txtDaysBehind
  1        A         Yes         Yes        0
  2        A         Yes         No         20
  3        A         Yes         No         40
```

I want to write On Change VBA code, so that when I change ID 1 to Active=No, these things happen: ID 1 Leading=No and ID 2 Leading=Yes (because it's the fewest days behind).

Since ID 1 is my current record, this code is easy enough:

```
cmbLeading = "No"
```

I've written code that identifies ID 2 as the new leader.

```
rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE Type='A' AND Active='Yes' ORDER BY DaysBehind")
```

How do I change the Leading value for ID 2?  I've tried this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table SET table.Leading='Yes' WHERE table.ID=2"
```

It isn't making any change to the table, and I'm guessing this is because I have the records open in the form.  Do I need to make the change on the form?  If so, how do I change a non-current record?

Comment: No.  It seems to run OK, it just doesn't actually seem to do anything.

Comment: Still no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  I needed to include a me.dirty=false to unlock the table.  In particular, I put in if me.dirty then me.dirty=false.